# Command Raised an exception: TypeError: string indicies must be integers

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am coding a discord.py bot and i have a command called slots.
I am using a function to update the balence of the user that runs the command.
The code is.

```py
async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]]
    return bal
```

But the error as said in the title is in this line.

```py
    bal = [users[str(user.id)["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]]
```

Here is the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/slots.py", line 54, in slots
    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author.id)
  File "/home/container/cogs/slots.py", line 38, in update_bank
    bal = [users[str(user)["wallet"], users[str(user)]["bank"]]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

If anyone can help that will be great

Comment: Are you sure about this - `users[str(user.id)["wallet"]` ?

Comment: Yeah im sure. That is how i get it in all of my other things.

Comment: Could you show an example of your `users` data? @Knife worm

Comment: https://pastebin.com/exP9vuCg Here u go

Comment: And i call that using this.
    users = await get_bank_data()

Comment: Thats fine, what I'm asking is the sample data returned from `get_bank_data()` and include that in your post please

Comment: Here you go.
https://pastebin.com/SkBdVSqG
this also works.
    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change
the mode being an argument parsed

Comment: It should be `users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]` @Knife worm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that you are simply missing the square bracket right here

```
bal = [users[str(user.id) ->]<- ["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]]
```